# Exponential of singular matrix times inverse of singular matrix

Tags: matrices, limits

I need to find a way to solve the following problem:

Suppose I have a singular matrix A. I need to find a solution to

$\frac{e^{hA}-I}{A}$

However, note that the inverse of A is infinity. Can anyone help with this problem? Maybe l'hospital rule could help? I am not really sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you say that you want to find a solution, you should write down an equation. Moreover, let us know what you have tried already and where your interest in this question comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't make sense, however the function $f(z) = \dfrac{e^{hz}-1}{z}$
has a removable singularity at $0$, and after removing it you have an entire function,
so you can define $f(A)$ by the functional calculus.  For example, you could compute
it using the power series
$$ f(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{h^n}{n!} A^{n-1} $$
Or if $A$ is diagonalizable: $A = S^{-1} D S$ where $D$ is diagonal, then
$f(A) = S^{-1} f(D) S$ where $f(D)$ is diagonal with $(f(D))_{jj} = f(D_{jj})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Sorry to bother again, but just to be clear, there is no way to get rid of the power series? I have used software to compute this series and it is a convergent series, therefore I would like to find a simple way to compute it which would not involve a summation of infinity terms!

Comment: There are many ways to compute it besides the series.  I noted one in the case where $A$ is diagonalizable.  More generally you could use Jordan canonical form.

Comment: See also Moler and van Loan, [Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S00361445024180)

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thank you very much again!